# How do you go through a text file and print the next number in python?

Tags: python, text-files

How do you go through a text file and print the next ascending number with other information (already able to do this)?

For my code I need to assign a number to something the user inputs and so far I am able to do everything but get the number to print onto the text file. I would like my file to be formatted in the following way:

*1    abcd*

*2    efgh*

I need the code to go through the text file and see what the highest number is then print the next number with the information. Like I said before I'm having no trouble with the information part just the part on adding the numbers.

I have thought about doing an *if* statement however that would mean going through a lot of numbers and sooner or later it will need updating with more numbers. As well as this, it would be very time consuming as well as memory consuming.

I have also thought about using a *for* statement however I haven't been able to find a way of it working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Considering your file in named "file.txt" and the lines are formatted as you specified, this would get it done:

```
s = list(map(lambda x: int(x.split()[0]), open('file.txt').read().split('\n')))
next = max(s) + 1
```

To add the user input with the next number, use this (with the previous lines):

```
data = input('Enter you data: ')
open('file.txt', 'a').write('\n' + str(next) + ' ' + data)
```

**Explained:**

`open('file.txt').read().split('\n')` - open the file, than split it by lines

`map(lambda x: int(x.split()[0]), ...)` - get the `integer` cast of the first element in each row

`list(...)` - cast the `map` object to a `list` indexed object

`max(s) + 1` - get the highest number retrieved, incremented by one

`open('file.txt', 'a')` - open the file in `appending` mode (don't flush the files, start from the end and appends)

`write('\n' + str(next) + ' ' + data)` - add the data with the next number in the specified format (`\n` for line down)

Answer (score 0):

Trying to make your own database. Use CSVs so you can offload the reading and parsing to an existing module. Use a database so you can handle auto-allocation of numbers, avoiding duplicate numbers, entries not in order, adding new columns, etc.

```
# Read the file and get the last line:
with open('data.txt') as f:
    last_line = f.readlines()[-1]


# Take the number from it and add a new number 
# (assumes the file is sorted so the biggest number is always on the last line)
# because if you're only using this script to add things, it always will be
last_num, _ = last_line.split(' ')
new_num = int(last_num) + 1


# Read from the user and make a new line:
new_text = input('Type stuff here: ')       
new_line = "{0} {1}".format(new_num, new_text)


# Write the new line ('a' is append mode)
with open('data.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.writeline(new_line)
```

Comment: I have tried this code and it doesn't work. I am currently having trouble with this following line: *last_num, _ = last_line.split(' ')*. It says you cannot split a list

Comment: @MadHatter I don't believe it says that unless you've changed the code to do something else. `file.readlines()` is a list of string lines, `list[-1]` is the last item in a list, it's a string, [you can split it just fine, look](https://repl.it/DalM).

Comment: on the line *new_num = int(last_num) + 1

* it says *int () argument must be a string or a number, not "list" *